# how to get date from datapicker , it shows me the date 1/1/1970

Tags: javascript, php, datetime, datepicker

please someone can help me how to get the date from DP
in this code its show me an exception and the date 01/01/1970

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html >
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" >
<title>Untitled 1</title>
</head>
<form  method="post" >
<input id="calendar" name="calendar" type="date"> 
</form>
<?php 
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_REQUEST['calendar']));
echo $new_date; 
var_dump($_REQUEST['calendar']);

?> 



</html>
```

Comment: What is in `$_POST['calendar']`?

Comment: it supposed to be the data from the datapicker, or the selected value

Comment: *"supposed to be"* and actually is are 2 different things and format matters also. What is actually there?

Comment: the selected value from the calendar

Comment: Where are you submitting a post?...or also checking if one was submitted?

Comment: i don't send this post anywhere , i check the value of $_POST['calendar'] and its NULL, and i don't know why

Comment: i edit the post for all of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did (Ubuntu) :

```
$ cd /tmp
$ cat index.php
<form  method="post" >
<input id="calendar" name="calendar" type="date"> 
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php 
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['calendar']));
echo $new_date . '<br>';
var_dump(strtotime($_POST['calendar']));
?>
$ php -S localhost:8080
```

Notice the "Submit" button. The last command starts the builtin PHP web server. Then I can show the page in my favorite web browser by typing "localhost:8080" in the address bar. When I pick a date and submit the form I can see the timestamp.

Comment: do you know maybe how can i catch this date without the submit button?

Comment: @nirbenzino https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48045135/how-to-get-date-from-datapicker-it-shows-me-the-date-1-1-1970/48045644?noredirect=1#comment83062565_48045636 ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to submit your form to have the value inside your $_POST (since your form use POST method). Without it, your $_POST['calendar'] isn't initialized.

To be sure your date isn't display without submit it, you had to check if your value $_POST['calendar'] is set (or regarding of your code, if any _$_POST variable is initialized).

```
<form  method="post" >
    <input id="calendar" name="calendar" type="date">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php
  // you could use if (!empty($_POST)) too, but be carefull, it check if ANY post data exist
  if( isset($_POST['calendar']) ){ // check if the value has been sent
      $new_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['calendar']));
      echo $new_date; 
  }
?>
```

To do more, you could add a check on the date, to be sure the input is right, like this :

```
  if( isset($_POST['calendar']) ){
      $new_date = strtotime($_POST['calendar']);
      if ($new_date){
         $new_date = date('Y-m-d',$new_date); 
         echo $new_date; 
      }else{
         echo 'Invalid Date: ' . $_POST['dateFrom'];
      }
  }
```

Comment: can i get this date value without the submit button?

Comment: @nirbenzino Yes you can, with a little JavaScript.

Comment: how can i do it?

Comment: Depending on how you want to use it, but I think you can use Javascript to catch it.

Comment: @nirbenzino You should try something by yourself and post a new question if you get stuck. Google : ["submit form using javascript"](https://www.google.fr/search?q=submit+form+using+javascript). For now please mark this answer as accepted :-)

Comment: how can I do it?

Comment: @nirbenzino Why don't you like the submit button ? x-)

Comment: hahaha no, how can I mark this post as accepted

Comment: @nirbenzino Haha :-D You should see a big check mark at the left side of the answer, not sure, maybe it depends on you reputation score.

Answer (score 1):

I would use PHP's DateTime class to convert it.

```
$date = '12/31/2017';

$DateTime = new DateTime($date);
echo $DateTime->format('Y-m-d');
```

As seen [here Live](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3dda945f86fc661525524eb06951cde6ba43a39e)

Outputs:

```
  '2017-12-31`
```

DateTime offers way more functionally and looks much cleaner then the `date` and `strtotime` "traditional" way of doing it.